# How to access Corresponding Inner List Item while using Streams

Tags: java

I have the following JSON Structure

```
{
    "employees": {
        "emp": [{
                "departments": {
                    "dept": [{
                        "code": "S",
                        "description": "FieldWork"
                    }]
                },
                "empidid": 35,
                "empname": "Mark"
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

Each **emp** is a List which has corresponding **dept List**
While looping emp as a List , i need corresponding Dept Code also

I am facing trouble getting the corresponding **dept code** while looping

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        String json = "{\r\n" + 
                "   \"employees\": {\r\n" + 
                "       \"emp\": [{\r\n" + 
                "               \"departments\": {\r\n" + 
                "                   \"dept\": [{\r\n" + 
                "                       \"code\": \"S\",\r\n" + 
                "                       \"description\": \"FieldWork\"\r\n" + 
                "                   }]\r\n" + 
                "               },\r\n" + 
                "               \"empidid\": 35,\r\n" + 
                "               \"empname\": \"Mark\"\r\n" + 
                "           }\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "       ]\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "}";
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        RootVal empResp = gson.fromJson(json, RootVal.class);
        
        Optional.ofNullable(empResp)
        .map(e -> e.getEmployees())
        .map(e -> e.getEmp())
        
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList).stream().map(emp -> {
            
            emp.getEmpidid();
            emp.getEmpidid();
            // How to get DEPT Code Here 
            return null;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        

    }
```

This is my class Structure

```
==================================

public class Dept
{
    private String code;

    private String description;

    public void setCode(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getCode(){
        return this.code;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }
}

==================================

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Departments
{
    private List<Dept> dept;

    public void setDept(List<Dept> dept){
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public List<Dept> getDept(){
        return this.dept;
    }
}

==================================

public class Emp
{
    private Departments departments;

    private int empidid;

    private String empname;

    public void setDepartments(Departments departments){
        this.departments = departments;
    }
    public Departments getDepartments(){
        return this.departments;
    }
    public void setEmpidid(int empidid){
        this.empidid = empidid;
    }
    public int getEmpidid(){
        return this.empidid;
    }
    public void setEmpname(String empname){
        this.empname = empname;
    }
    public String getEmpname(){
        return this.empname;
    }
}

==================================

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Employees
{
    private List<Emp> emp;

    public void setEmp(List<Emp> emp){
        this.emp = emp;
    }
    public List<Emp> getEmp(){
        return this.emp;
    }
}

==================================

public class Root
{
    private Employees employees;

    public void setEmployees(Employees employees){
        this.employees = employees;
    }
    public Employees getEmployees(){
        return this.employees;
    }
}
```

Please let me how to access Corresponding Dept Code while looping emp List

Comment: You can get departments using `getDepartments` annotation, and use it thereafter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the field's getter method of `Emp` class and so on like

```
emp -> emp.getDepartments().getDept()
```

Here, `getDept()` return `List<Dept>` so to get `code`, you can use getter for each `Dept` object of list. Like `.get(0).getCode()` to get first element's `code` of `Dept` list.

Full code:

```
Optional.ofNullable(empResp)
    .map(e -> e.getEmployees())
    .map(e -> e.getEmp())
    
    .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList).stream().map(emp -> {
        emp.getEmpidid();
        emp.getEmpidid();
        // How to get DEPT Code Here 
        emp.getDepartments().getDept().get(0).getCode();
        return null;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```